# What happens if I remove .list files in sources.list.d?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

So let's say I add custom sources (`.list` files) to my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory and install packages from these sources.

What happens if I then remove the sources? Will `apt` be able to see that the package's source has been removed and give me a warning? Or will I effectively strand these packages- unable to be updated or otherwise managed by `apt`?

Comment: Unable to be updated, yes - unless they're in some other add repo. apt will still track those packages, and you can remove them using apt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages may still be updated, if a newer version of the package is available from a different repository which is still included in the sources listing.

However, yes, removing a file from that directory will result in the cache losing whatever repositories were listed in those files, the next time the cache is updated with `apt update`. This means you will no longer be able to install packages from those repositories, and any packages you installed from there which are not available from other repositories, will be left installed with no way to update, until the dependency graph is broken and they need to be removed (such as when upgrading from one version of Ubuntu to the next).